# Azure multi-tenant OAuth 20.0 app Web API scenario consent via portal

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, active-directory, multi-tenant

There is a Client in Tenant A. There is a Resource Server (`Web API`) in Tenant B. I'm developing both `Client` and `Web API`. I'm admin in both Tenant A and B. `OAuth 2.0` grant type is Client Credentials so no `End-User`is involved. My Web API (`AAD App`) exposes AppRoles which I described in `Web API (AAD App)` manifest (I named one of them `client_access`). For both `AAD Apps`(`Client` and `Web API`) I turned on multi-tenant option. And they have globally unique App ID URIs.

Now Client `(AAD App`) wants to request permissions to access `Web API`in this role (`client_access`). Because they are in different tenants I created a Service Principal representing the Client in Tenant B. Now I want that Admin of Tenant B would provide this Service Principal with permissions/consent on requested role client_access providing by `Web API`.

But how (being an Admin of a Tenant) using `Azure Portal`can I find this Service Principal? App registration page shows only `AAD Apps`but not Service Principals. I don't see Client`AAD App`either (in App registration page in Tenant B).

With single tenant situation everything is easy -- I select Client, go to Required permission section, push `Add button`, find there my `Web API`and check `client_access checkbox`, then I push button Grant Permissions to provide my consent.

**Anyone have a clue on How to provide permissions for Client to access Web API in multi-tenant scenario using Azure Portal or PowerShell or other means?** 
Maybe my overall approach is wrong? So advice please.

P.S.
We will publish/expose this `Web API`to many of our partners so they  will be able to develop their own Clients (residing in their tenants). They will requests access and I will grant/consent/approve their requests to my `Web API`. And after permission is established the Clients will communicate with `Web API`using `OAuth 2.0` Client Credentials grant type with an access token.

Thank you